# Cannot retrieve populated array from a function

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsurlsession

I have a function `getZipCodefromURL` that retrieves data from a weather data service, parses the json, and sorts information into my `array`. In my App, I have a textfield, a button, and labels set up so that a user can input his or her zip code in the textfield and hit the button which will update the labels with info about the weather in their area.

I think the problem I'm facing is from the way my function is set up or the way I'm calling it. In my `enterButton` function, I want to retrieve my populated array from `getZipCodeinURL` , however when I call it, it returns empty and I can't index it. So far this is what I have:

```
    var array: [String] = []

    func getZipCodeinURL(zipCode: String) -> NSArray{
           let urlPath = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=\(zipCode),us&units=imperial"
            let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
                    println(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                var err: NSError?
                var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
                if err != nil {
                    // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
                    println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                let json = JSON(jsonResult)
                var temp = json["main"]["temp"].stringValue
                var humidity = json["main"]["humidity"].stringValue
                var pressure = json["main"]["pressure"].stringValue
                self.array = [temp, humidity, pressure]
            })
            task.resume()
         return array
        }

@IBOutlet weak var pressureLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var humidityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tempLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func enterButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        var zipCode = zipcodeText.text
        var weatherArray: NSArray = getZipCodeinURL(zipCode)
        var temperature: AnyObject = weatherArray[0]
            }
```

Does anyone know how I can properly retrieve my populated `array` from my function into my `enterButton` function?

Comment: You need to do some studying on asynchronous calls with focus on Internet calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rest of your code is correct, the mistake you are making is that the call to `NSURLSessionDataTask.resume()` is asynchronous. It will return while the network call is being made (before `array` has been populated with results in the completion block you provided). Therefore `return array` will correctly return the empty array that you have declared above.

To rectify this, have your `getZipCodeinURL` return nothing. Inside the completion block, make a call to another function (e.g. make a `didFinishLoadingArray`) which will use the array do work . Make this call after your `self.array = ...`. Then change the `enterButton` function to just initiate the data retrieval.  It will look something like this:

```
var array: [String] = []

func getZipCodeinURL(zipCode: String) {
        let urlPath = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=\(zipCode),us&units=imperial"
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        var err: NSError?
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if err != nil {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        let json = JSON(jsonResult)
        var temp = json["main"]["temp"].stringValue
        var humidity = json["main"]["humidity"].stringValue
        var pressure = json["main"]["pressure"].stringValue
        self.array = [temp, humidity, pressure]
        didFinishLoadingArray()
    })
    task.resume()
}

@IBOutlet weak var pressureLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var humidityLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tempLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func enterButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var zipCode = zipcodeText.text
    getZipCodeinURL(zipCode)       
}

func didFinishLoadingArray() {
    var temperature: AnyObject = self.array[0]
}
```

If you are updating the UI in this fashion, you will also need to make sure you do this on the main thread. Look up how to do that.

Comment: how would I go about retrieving `temp` in my enterButton function in this way?

Answer (score -1):

Check out [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and look specifically at response Handling.

Essentially you can make a `GET` call and tell code to execute once that call has had a response. Alamofire also integrates directly with SwiftyJSON. Making it very easy to prase your responseJSON.

You can very easily do something like this.

```
@IBAction func enterButton(sender: AnyObject) {
   getZipCodeinURL(zipCode)
}


func getZipCodeinURL(zipCode: String){
     Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=\(zipCode),us&units=imperial")
        .responseJSON { jsonResult in
           debugPrint(jsonResult)

            let json = JSON(jsonResult)
            var temp = json["main"]["temp"].stringValue
            var humidity = json["main"]["humidity"].stringValue
            var pressure = json["main"]["pressure"].stringValue

            var weatherArray: NSArray = [temp, humidity, pressure]
            var temperature: AnyObject = temp
        }

}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I don't see where your function  is returning the array

Comment: My Bad, forgot to remove some of the code I copied and pasted. Edited answer to accomodate. But essentially you want to set you variables after you have had a response to your call. Because it takes time to send a call to a web server and get a response.